# blender viewport is rotating around an unknown point

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, customization

In blender 2.73 , when i scroll with my  MBP trackpad to rotate around my cube , it does not rotate around the cube as center. but it rotates around another point not too far from the cube.

I checked online for how to set pivot points and found menu->object-> transform->geometry_to_origin,  and a few more options , but the rotation point is still not the center of the cube itself.
the only way for me to get back to normal  is to close this file and open a new file from start.

i want to rotate the view , with the cube as center , just as it did when you open a new file. what is the trick to fix this ?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise is this not a duplicate ?

Comment: It wasn't flagged, but maybe. Did you find one?

Comment: I've cleaned up the obsolete comments. If there is a dupe candidate, please flag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the viewport rotate around the selected object go to **User Preferences** and check **Rotate Around Selection**:

[image]