# Camera Positioning (Similar to Maya?)

Tags: 3d-view

So when I used Maya, I was able to pan the viewport around, and wherever the center of the viewport was, I would rotate around that, instead of some other rotation point. Is there a way for me to set this to be the default in Blender? Thanks!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/696/how-to-reset-the-center-of-rotation-of-the-3d-view-when-it-is-not-the-center-of

Comment: Also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26523/blender-viewport-is-rotating-around-an-unknown-point

Answer (score 3):

When you are in he camera view (<kbd>numpad 0</kbd>), you can either use the "lock camera to view" option in the right menu in the viewport (open with <kbd>N</kbd>).
[image]

or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for a egoshooter-like camera control (<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to move, <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> to move up and down and tab to enable gravity and finally the mousewheel to control your speed). I think this is the best option for camera positioning.

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten all about this. Makes it much easier to quickly animate a camera view without using paths.